# Create a multilanguage standard page in Typo3

Tags: typo3, multilingual

I would like to create a multilanguage standard page in typo3. I'm using typo3 6.2.9 and moox_template_free001. Any ideas on how to handle i18n in this CMS?

Answer (score 0):

There are several tutorials showing how to prepare TYPO3 for multi language support, i.e.: http://www.training-typo3.com/2008/12/15/typo3-multi-language/

It's quiet advanced process, but when performed step by step, will allow you to translate your pages(s).